# Detection of change in variance and mean in time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, mean, variance

I am trying to to detect change in variance and mean in the time series

the code I am using is as follows

```
d1_markets<-subset(d1,d1$Category=="Markets")
d1_markets_series<- ts(d1_markets[,3], frequency=7)
library(changepoint)
out=cpt.meanvar(d1_markets_series)
```

My series looks like this -

```
       actual
  [1,]    511
  [2,]    901
  [3,]    753
  [4,]    646
  [5,]    602
```

I am getting the following error when i run the `cpt.meanvar()`

> Error in single.meanvar.norm(data, penalty, pen.value, class, param.estimates,  : 
>     Data must have atleast 4 observations to fit a changepoint model.

Can you please help me solve this? The series has data, not sure why this error is coming up

Comment: The error says it is not having at least 4 observations.  Have you checked that.  Please provide a small reproducible example that shows the errror

Comment: do you want me to paste the series ?

Comment: I have 240 observations in the series

Comment: Just a small data with `dput` (that shows the error) that would help others in examining the issue